# Centering an element when it has a fixed top position (CSS)

Tags: css

I'm wondering if it's possible, even though I've set my element to be fixed, with a `top: 0` position, can I center it, or does it require a left position as well?

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </header>
```

Comment: what do you want to center it on?

Comment: either `header h1 { text-align: center; }` or flexbox `header { display: flex; justify-content: center; }` will horizontally center.

Comment: updated the duplicate with a better one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto` on a fixed element doesn't work by itself. But by adding left and right as 0 it will. Also this snippet adds a `text-align: center` so the text is aligned within the element.

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>header text</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you are setting position to fixed. Wrap your element in a container with fixed position and set the element position to relative, with `margin: auto` [(1)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

```css
header {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.full-width: {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=full-width>
  <header>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Good, but only problem is it creates a margin above the header element.

Comment: Then you might want to specify border, margin, border, padding in both the container and the header element itself. Please check https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp